# Using postConditions with CakePHPs Security Component

Tags: cakephp

For a basic search on a Model in Cake, I have been using the [postConditions](http://book.cakephp.org/view/989/postConditions) method. It was working well until I enabled CSRF protection via the Security Component.

Enabling this component produces `SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column '_Token.key' in 'where clause [...]` and I can see that this is happening because `$this->data` has changed from:

```
Array (
    [CrmPerson] => Array
        (
            [firstname] => john
            [surname] => 
            [email] => 
        )
)
```

....to.....

```
Array
(
    [_Token] => Array
        (
            [key] => 03aef38c3c2f631d6dc50baa98c7327a3fe6d0cd
            [fields] => 71d0fa03bc4e10f6f4d0de8f91674100836ea498%3A
        )

    [CrmPerson] => Array
        (
            [firstname] => john
            [surname] => 
            [email] => 
        )

)
```

In other words, the presence of `[_Token]` up upsetting the `$this->postConditions` call.

My entire find() function in the controller looks like this:

```
function find() {
    if(!empty($this->data)) {
        $this->CrmPerson->recursive = 0;
        $conditions = $this->postConditions(
            $this->data,
            array(
                'firstname' => 'LIKE',
                'surname' => 'LIKE',
                'email' => 'LIKE'
            )
        );

        $this->paginate = array(
            'order' => 'CrmPerson.created DESC',
            'limit' => '40',
        );
        $this->set('crmPeople', $this->paginate($conditions));
    }
}
```

I tried changing `$this->data` to `$this->data['CrmPerson']` but the postConditions method needs the data to start one level higher up in the array.

Do I need to create a whole new array to give to postConditions or is there a simpler option I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I was having a slow Sunday... just re-read the postConditions() method @params in controller.php and I can see where I've gone wrong.

This:

```
        $conditions = $this->postConditions(
            $this->data,
            array(
                'firstname' => 'LIKE',
                'surname' => 'LIKE',
                'email' => 'LIKE'
        );
```

... needs to be....

```
        $conditions = $this->postConditions(
            $this->data,
            array(
                'firstname' => 'LIKE',
                'surname' => 'LIKE',
                'email' => 'LIKE'
            ),'AND',true
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> unset($this->data['_Token']);
> ```

Comment: This answers my query as I asked it so I'm marking it as the right answer. However, I have also posted another answer which solves this problem directly in the method.

Comment: you should mark your answer as the correct one, because it is.